# Plumbing for API Gateway to Beanstalk with SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway

I am looking to host an API which I can control customer access to using API Keys, Usage Plans, and Cognito. This is my first time trying to bootstrap DNS+SSL and I can't figure out the basic plumbing to get SSL working when I connect API gateway to my beanstalk environment.

I've got example.com purchased on namecheap. I've got namecheap DNS set up to forward the api subdomain to AWS DNS via an NS record. I've got an API gateway with a custom domain name of api.example.com mapped to an API with a production stage. I've then got route 53 set up to point api.example.com to that API gateway stage. I can curl api.example.com and because I have a cognito user pool authenticator, I see Unauthorized as the response.

What I'm stuck on is how to connect this to my elastic beanstalk environment. My current attempt involves turning the API Gateway into a "HTTP Proxy", and tweaking the endpoint url. Except I'm not sure what to put there, or how to configure what I put there because the Test button in API GW often throws an error.

I'm currently trying to use the domain name of the load balancer in front of beanstalk: [https://load-balancer-in-front-of-beanstalk-endpoint.com/{proxy}](https://load-balancer-in-front-of-beanstalk-endpoint.com/%7Bproxy%7D). I've tried a few configs on that load balancer, but I'm not sure what cert to give it because when I try api.example.com,
it fails with "Host name dualstack.awseb.foo.elb.amazonaws.com does not match the cert provided by peer(api.example.com)".

Some other questions mentioned setting an alias for api.example.com to point to the load balancer's ip... except for me it already points to the API GW, so I think I've gone wrong somewhere. Could use some pointers.

Comment: Did you setup SSL certs on your load balancer with your own domain that you try to use `https` for it?

Comment: Thanks for responding @Marcin. What do you think of this workaround I just came up with? I'm not sure if this is the best approach. I made a new cert for myloadbalancer.example.com, pointed the API gateway at that, and then created a route 53 alias to map myloadbalancer.example.com to the load balancer's actual endpoint, and then had to make another NS record in namecheap to map myloadbalancer to route 53.

Comment: You can do everything from Route53 if NameCheaps nameservers point to your hosted zone in R53's. Once you do this, eveything is done in R53, including creation of new subdomains.